# Grails: Quartz job not getting triggered after deploying WAR

Tags: tomcat, grails, quartz-scheduler, war

Here's my dilemma: I have a Quartz job that works locally. When I deploy the WAR file to a Tomcat server, I don't see the job getting triggered. I know that it would not get triggered if under "test" environment, so I deployed using `grails prod war`.

Are there any other possible config/settings that I need to do? 
Anything on the server that is causing this?

I don't see any errors in the log file, just the job not getting triggered. Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure in `QuartzConfig.groovy` you have `autostart` set to `true` for production environment.

Comment: I'll check that. Thanks. Weird that I just deployed it to our UAT server and it works fine. Something so weird on the our other server.